# VB.Net between two number find code

Tags: vb.net

I have alphanumeric strings like `S00125701`. How do I find numbers in between?

```
Case H00125701 To H00125859
    Label1.Text = "Box # 110"
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You want to strip the first *letter* off of the string and get only the number? Or something else? And then what?

Comment: Agreeing with Cody.  If you strip the letter off and subtract the remaining two numbers, the answer is not 110.

Comment: @dbasnett - I don't think the 110 is supposed to be a subtraction, I think it is simply a label to be used for that particular range in the SELECT CASE. I may be wrong of course!

Comment: In order for us to help, you need to better describe your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can `Select Case` directly on the string:

```
 Select Case string
        Case "H00125701" To "H00125859"
            Label1.Text = "Box # 110"
    End Select
```

If your problem is that your input string starts with `S` but you have to test against strings which begin with `H` then a `Replace` will work:

```
 Select Case string.Replace("S", "H")
        Case "H00125701" To "H00125859"
            Label1.Text = "Box # 110"
    End Select
```

If your problem is that your input string could start with any letter but you have to test against strings which begin with `H` (or any other letter for that matter) and there will only ever be a single letter then a `Substring` and `Convert` will work:

```
 Select Case Convert.ToInt32(string.Substring(1))
        Case 125701 To 125859
            Label1.Text = "Box # 110"
    End Select
```

Comment: My god, I had no idea this case notation existed. Beautiful!